# Shorter way of POSTs validation?

Tags: php

I always do POST's check validation, sometime its get too messy and long. What is the best way to keep it shorter and tidy?

Example:

```
if (isset($_POST['albumName']) && trim($_POST['albumName']) != "" && isset($_POST['slugName']) && $_POST['slugName'] != "" && is_numeric($_POST['PhotoCatID'])) {
  //All good
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [standard Filter extension](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.filter.php) may have what you're looking for, [`filter_input`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.filter-input.php) in particular:

```
$albumName = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'albumName', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRIPPED);
$slugNamed = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'slugName', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRIPPED);
$PhotoCatId = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'PhotoCatId', FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
```

(I personally ended up writing wrappers named `filter_get`, `filter_post` and `filter_request` just to make the lines a bit shorter...)

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking to cut down your duplicate code and improve your logic, look into creating a validation class, will allow you to centralise all the validation logic.

Lots of resources on validation classes:

- http://www.phpclasses.org/browse/file/5200.html
- http://www.devshed.com/c/a/PHP/Building-An-Extensible-Form-Validator-Class/

Also  you have PHP built-in FILTER extension, which allows you to both sanitize and validate data.

- http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/sanitize-and-validate-data-with-php-filters/

Answer (score 0):

First. Write vertically, not horizontally.
If you have several statements, write it one under another, not in one enormous line

Next, some validations can be be applied in a loop:

```
foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) $_POST[$key] = trim($value);
```

Next, some statements can be shortened.

```
$err=array();
if (empty($_POST['albumName'])) $err[]= "Album name is empty";
if (empty($_POST['slugName'])) $err[]= "Slug name is empty";
if (!is_numeric($_POST['PhotoCatID'])) $err[]= "Wrong parameters";

if(!$err) {
  //All good
}
```

The rest is depends on your needs.

Answer (score 0):

For IDs you can save yourself alot of trouble and just typecast them to int

```
$id = (int)$_POST['id'];
```

If the value is not valid, $id will be set to 0.