# Implement LIKE in PHP prepared Statements with % wildcards

Tags: php, mysql

I'm working on setting up a basic search query for my database and returning it to a table.  I'm running into an issue with the syntax to use within prepared statements.

I based my initial setup on a w3schools example.

The search input comes from a form on an `html page`.  This calls the `php file`.

Within the `php file`, I connect to the `SQL server` and execute the following:

```
$search = $_POST['search'];

$stmt = $link->prepare("SELECT lname, fname FROM planner WHERE lname LIKE ?");
$stmt->bind_param('s', $search);
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->get_result();

print_r($result);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
echo "<table><tr><th>Last Name</th><th>First Name</th></tr>";
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo "<tr><td>".$row["lname"]."</td><td>".$row["fname"]."</td></tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
} else {
echo "0 results";
}
```

The challenge I'm running into is how to define the `parameters` for the LIKE to evaluate within the prepared statement construct.  W3Schools give lots of examples of `LIKE parameters` using various combinations of `letters and %`, but I'm not sure where to put these in the prepared statement.  I want to base the lname results on the search criteria provided from the form on the html page.

Several old posts on this site point to setting the criteria within a string.  I'm not sure exactly how it works.  If that's a good way to go about it, I'd like to know more about what's going on with this method.

Appreciate any help you all can provide.

Comment: It's not clear what you want to do here. What do you mean by "define the parameters for the LIKE to evaluate within the prepared statement construct". It looks like you are doing that already. The prepared statement gets sent to mysql and the variable is replaced by your search parameter. Are you getting any errors?

Comment: include the `%` with the variable value so if you have `$name` than you have to add the wild cards like this `$name.'%'` begins with. Do not add it to the SQL like this `LIKE ?%` it's a common issue.  or in your example `bind_param('s', $search.'%');`

Comment: The basic question you're asking is what are the operators for a LIKE clause. The answer to that is that `%` is a wildcard search that searches 0 or more characters. _ matches exactly a single character. So `te%` would match `test`, `tea`, and `teal` while `te_` would match only `tea`.  https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_like.asp

Comment: Kodos,  I don't get any errors, just zero results everytime, even if I enter a lname exactly how it is in the database

Comment: What is your search string and what do you think it should match.

Comment: ArtisticPhoenix, thanks I'll give that a try.  I was playing around with options on the ? as well as $_POST['search'}....Didn't think to add it to the bind.

Comment: PressingOnAlways, thanks, that's what I read on w3school as well.

Comment: also do you  have `PHPmyadmin` for database work?  IF so take the query itself and run it right in there, that way if you get results in `PHPmyadmin` but not the page you know something else is wrong in your code.  You can do  `echo str_replace('?', "'".$search"'", $sql)` to output the query assing its stored in `$sql` etc.  Don't use that to build a query as it defeats the purpose of preparing them.

Comment: ArtisticPhoenix,  I now get an error...Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Cannot pass parameter 2 by reference in D:\xampp\htdocs\php\mentor.php:91 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in D:\xampp\htdocs\php\mentor.php on line 91

Comment: I've got PHPMyadmin and can run the query at the console.

Comment: Ok, It's dinner time for me( my wife will get mad if I ignore her) sorry, and good luck.  Plus she made her famous stuffed bell peepers :-)

Comment: My search string I use is "john", which should match lastnames (lname) like johnson which I have in my database.

Comment: you would need `john%` with a wildcard.

Comment: Thanks ArtisticPhoenix, wife always come first.

Comment: If that is one of `Several old posts on this site` you already saw please update the question to show your usage of the wildcard `%`.

Comment: chris85, I've played around with that one a bit, but it isn't addressing the wildcard syntax I'm asking about here.  I updated the question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I want to thank everyone for their help with this.  ArtisticPhoenix got me headed in the right direction.

This post hit the mark of what I was looking for to bring it all together:

[Adding a wildcard character to a string in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5657660/adding-a-wildcard-character-to-a-string-in-php)

Here's the "slightly" updated code:

```
    $search = $_POST['search'].'%';

    //echo($search);

    $stmt = $link->prepare("SELECT lname, fname FROM planner WHERE lname LIKE ?");
    $stmt->bind_param('s', $search);
    $stmt->execute();
    $result = $stmt->get_result();

    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    echo "<table><tr><th>Last Name</th><th>First Name</th></tr>";
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "<tr><td>".$row["lname"]."</td><td>".$row["fname"]."</td></tr>";
    }
    echo "</table>";
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
```

Comment: It will search the last index matches, better will be-> $search = '%'.$_POST['search'].'%'; Which will search full string. Thanks airider.. I'm having this problem recently..

Answer (score 3):

**You can do like's keyword work in sql like this simply**

-> To search only for lname

```
$search = $_POST['search'];
$stmt = $link->prepare("SELECT * FROM planner WHERE lname like ?");
$stmt->execute(array("%".$search."%"));
```

-> To search both for lname and fname just do this->

```
 $search = $_POST['search'];
 $stmt = $link->prepare("SELECT * FROM planner WHERE lname like ? OR fname like ? ");
 $stmt->execute(array("%".$search."%", "%".$search."%"));
```

Comment: This is close, but the `execute` binding is exclusive to PDO. OP is using `mysqli`.